# Is there a way to run SSP without DataTables and PHP only

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I use Server Side Processing (through DataTables) within an application to speed up  a query that retrieves a large number of records.

I'd like to do the same, but on some pages that do not use DataTables.  Also, is it possible to do this without AJAX and strictly through PHP?  The reason that I ask that is because there are times I'd like to speed up queries with large results that are going into php arrays.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you use pagination, caching (ex: Redis,memcached, etc) or database indexing?

Comment: pagination can also be slow @Dimi when using LIMIT with a large offset like 1000000, 100 MySQL needs to fetch 1000100 records to drop 1000000 again.

Comment: I'm not doing any pagination or displaying the data for this particular instance.   I simply want to use the server side processing to speed up the data acquisition